# How to mock jest.spyOn for a specific axios call

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios, spyon

How do I mock a specific axios call?
Imagine 2 GET calls:

```
await axios.get('api/numbers');
await axios.get('api/letters');
```

Then this is going on in the test:

```
const mockGet = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
mockGet.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve({ data: 1 }));
mockGet.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve({ data: 'a' }));
```

How do I create a condition for `mockReturnValueOnce` based on the url passed to axios (say for `'api/numbers'` -> return `Promise.resolve({ data: 1 })`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So far, there is no method of `jestjs` to do this. Here is the proposal: [Parameterised mock return values](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6180)

Here are the solutions:

1. Use `sinon.js`

`sinon.js` support mock the returned value based on the arguments, there is a method named `stub.withArgs(arg1[, arg2, ...]);`

2. Use [jest-when](https://github.com/timkindberg/jest-when) - A when(fn).calledWith(args).thenReturn(value) lib for jest
3. If you insist on using `jestjs`, since `mockReturnValueOnce` returns values sequentially(first call, second call, etc.). You can use the below way:

`index.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export async function main() {
  const numbersRes = await axios.get('api/numbers');
  const lettersRes = await axios.get('api/letters');
  return { numbersRes, lettersRes };
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { main } from '.';
import axios from 'axios';

describe('59751925', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mockGet = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
    mockGet.mockImplementation((url) => {
      switch (url) {
        case 'api/numbers':
          return Promise.resolve({ data: 1 });
        case 'api/letters':
          return Promise.resolve({ data: 'a' });
      }
    });
    const actual = await main();
    expect(actual.numbersRes).toEqual({ data: 1 });
    expect(actual.lettersRes).toEqual({ data: 'a' });
  });
});
```

Unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59751925/index.test.js (11.168s)
  59751925
    ✓ should pass (9ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.098s
```

Comment: I confirm point 3. answers the original question! Thanks for the solution!