# How to refactor my test to use Jest's Manual Mock feature?

Tags: testing, axios, jestjs, mocking, vuex

I am able to get a basic test working with Jest, but when I try to refactor it to use Jest's manual mocks features, the test no longer works.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Thank you for your time

error message:

```
TypeError: _backendService.default.post is not a function

      16 |
      17 |     return $axios
    > 18 |       .post(`${RESOURCE_PATH}/batch_upload/`, formData, {
         |        ^
      19 |         headers: {
      20 |           "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      21 |         },
```

in tests/.../`actions.spec.js`:

```
//import $axios from "@/services/backend-service"; // could not get manual mock to work
import actions from "@/store/modules/transactions/actions";

//jest.mock("@/services/backend-service"); // could not get manual mock to work

// this bit of code works
jest.mock("@/services/backend-service", () => {
  return {
    post: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
  };
});
// this bit of code works:end

describe("store/modules/transactions/actions", () => {
  it("uploads transactions succeeds", async() => {
    const state = {
      commit: jest.fn(),
    };

    await actions.uploadTransactions(
      state,
      {'file': 'arbitrary filename'}
    )

    expect(state.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('changeUploadStatusToSucceeded');
  });
});
```

in src/.../`__mocks__/backend-service.js`:

```
const mock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    post: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(),
  };
});

export default mock;
```

in src/.../`backend-service.js`:

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_BASE_URL =
  `${process.env["VUE_APP_BACKEND_SCHEME"]}` +
  `://` +
  `${process.env["VUE_APP_BACKEND_HOST"]}` +
  `:` +
  `${process.env["VUE_APP_BACKEND_PORT"]}` +
  `/` +
  `${process.env["VUE_APP_BACKEND_PATH_PREFIX"]}`;

const $axios = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
  },
});

export default $axios;
```

in src/.../`actions.js`:

```
import $axios from "@/services/backend-service";

const RESOURCE_NAME = "transaction";
const RESOURCE_PATH = `${RESOURCE_NAME}s`;

export const actions = {
  uploadTransactions(state, payload) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", payload["file"]);

    return $axios
      .post(`${RESOURCE_PATH}/batch_upload/`, formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        state.commit("changeUploadStatusToSucceeded");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          state.commit("changeUploadStatusToFailed");
        }
      });
  },
};

export default actions;
```

I've tried looking at examples from these resources, but nothing worked for me:

mocking Axios Interceptors: [Mocking axios with Jest throws error “Cannot read property 'interceptors' of undefined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973960/mocking-axios-with-jest-throws-error-cannot-read-property-interceptors-of-und)
overriding mock implmentations:

- [Mock.mockImplementation() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771844/mock-mockimplementation-not-working)
- [How do I change the mock implementation of a function in a mock module in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64350855/how-do-i-change-the-mock-implementation-of-a-function-in-a-mock-module-in-jest)
- [How to change mock implementation on a per single test basis [Jestjs]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790927/how-to-change-mock-implementation-on-a-per-single-test-basis-jestjs)

Jest Mock Documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn
Jest Manual Mock documentation:

- https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks
- https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#examples

using 3rd party libraries: https://vhudyma-blog.eu/3-ways-to-mock-axios-in-jest/

simple actions test example: https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vuex-actions.html#creating-the-action

outdated actions test example:

- https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/testing.html#testing-actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps others, I ended up just using spies and did not need to use manual mocks.

These were references that helped me figure it out:

https://silvenon.com/blog/mocking-with-jest/functions
https://silvenon.com/blog/mocking-with-jest/modules/
[How to mock jest.spyOn for a specific axios call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751925/how-to-mock-jest-spyon-for-a-specific-axios-call)

And here's the example code that ended up working for me:

in tests/.../`actions.spec.js`:

```
import $axios from "@/services/backend-service";
import actions from "@/store/modules/transactions/actions";

describe("store/modules/transactions/actions", () => {
  let state;
  let postSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    state = {
      commit: jest.fn(),
    };
    postSpy = jest.spyOn($axios, 'post')
  });

  it("uploads transactions succeeds", async() => {
    postSpy.mockImplementation(() => {
      return Promise.resolve();
    });

    await actions.uploadTransactions(
      state,
      {'file': 'arbitrary filename'},
    )

    expect(state.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('changeUploadStatusToSucceeded');
  });

  it("uploads transactions fails", async() => {
    postSpy.mockImplementation(() => {
      return Promise.reject({
        response: true,
      });
    });

    await actions.uploadTransactions(
      state,
      {'file': 'arbitrary filename'},
    )

    expect(state.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('changeUploadStatusToFailed');
  });
});
```

in src/.../`actions.js`:

```
import $axios from "@/services/backend-service";

const RESOURCE_NAME = "transaction";
const RESOURCE_PATH = `${RESOURCE_NAME}s`;

export const actions = {
  uploadTransactions(state, payload) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("account_id", 1); // change to get dynamically when ready
    formData.append("file", payload["file"]);

    //$axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    //  state.commit("changeUploadStatusToUploading");
    //  return config;
    //});

    return $axios
      .post(`${RESOURCE_PATH}/batch_upload/`, formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        state.commit("changeUploadStatusToSucceeded");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          state.commit("changeUploadStatusToFailed");
        }
      });
  },
};

export default actions;
```